# Scala shorthand for ending a stream?

Tags: scala

In practicing with Streams I'm discovering a common pattern of ending a stream like this:

```
Stream.cons(lastValue, Stream.empty)
```

This seems like it would be such a common pattern that there is probably a shorthand. Maybe like this?

```
Stream.finish(lastValue) // Not actual Scala code
```

Is such a function built into Scala?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The natural choice, `Stream(lastValue)`, doesn't work in general because `apply` is not lazy, but you can use it when you don't care that you've already assigned the value.

You could possibly use `Stream.fill(1)(lastValue)` when you want the value lazily computed, but it's not exactly obvious why one would use this construct (e.g. it makes one wonder if maybe you would want a number other than 1).

I would favor

```
lastValue #:: Stream.empty
```

personally.

Comment: `lastValue #:: Stream.empty` looks like a Stream version of `lastValue :: Nil` used by Lists. So why not use `Stream(lastValue)` as we do with lists `List(lastValue)`

Comment: `Stream.apply` is not lazy but if you use it to end a Stream you can have something like `3 #:: Stream("a".toInt)`. The error will raise only when we take the second element.

Comment: @LRLucena - Yes, in that particular case you can do it.  Personally, though, I prefer the visual of `3 #:: "a".toInt #:: Stream.empty`.

Answer (score 1):

Try `Stream(lastValue)` . I think that´s what you need to end a Stream.

You can use it like

```
3 #:: Stream(4)
```

Comment: Actually, no. I'm trying to learn Scala by going through ProjectEuler problems, but now I'm starting to think a book might be better.